# Singleton implementation of Cache Dependency Manager

Tags: c#, cache, asp.net-mvc, singleton

I am trying to implement a singleton CacheDependencyManager, by combining  [this CacheDependencyManager from Steve Greatrex](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/02/28/explicitly-controlling-cache-dependencies-in-mvc/) with a [singleton pattern from Jon Skeet (example 6)](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

I'd really appreciate any feedback on it's correctness and / or suggestions for improvement.

---

**ExplicitCacheDependency**

```
public class ExplicitCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private string _uniqueId;

    public ExplicitCacheDependency(string uniqueId)
        : base(new string[0]) //no file system dependencies
    {
        _uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public override string GetUniqueID()
    {
        return _uniqueId;
    }


    // CacheDependency has a protected NotifyDependencyChanged method that will notify the caching framework that the cached item is no longer valid. 
    // In most implementations this would be invoked in some callback, but for our purposes we can just add a new Invalidate method and invoke it directly
    public void Invalidate()
    {
        base.NotifyDependencyChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

---

**CacheDependencyManager**

```
public sealed class CacheDependencyManager
{
    private static readonly Lazy<CacheDependencyManager> lazy =
        new Lazy<CacheDependencyManager>(() => new CacheDependencyManager());

    public static CacheDependencyManager Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private CacheDependencyManager()
    {
    }


    private Dictionary<string, ExplicitCacheDependency> _dependencies
        = new Dictionary<string, ExplicitCacheDependency>();

    public CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string key)
    {
        if (!_dependencies.ContainsKey(key))
            _dependencies.Add(key, new ExplicitCacheDependency(key));

        return _dependencies[key];
    }

    public void InvalidateDependency(string key)
    {
        if (_dependencies.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var dependency = _dependencies[key];
            dependency.Invalidate();
            dependency.Dispose();
            _dependencies.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `CacheDependencyManager` is a singleton it should be thread safe.

[ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) is a nice fit for this.

Using `ConcurrentDictionary`the code would look like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ExplicitCacheDependency> _dependencies = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ExplicitCacheDependency>();

public CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string key)
{
    return _dependencies.GetOrAdd(key, k => new ExplicitCacheDependency(k));
}

public void InvalidateDependency(string key)
{
    ExplicitCacheDependency dependency;
    if (_dependencies.TryRemove(key, out dependency))
    {
        dependency.Invalidate();
        dependency.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary` looks interesting, I've never come across that before. Doesn't using `System.Lazy<T>` make it thread safe? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: I can see how `Lazy<T>` makes initialization thread safe but nothing more.

Comment: Ah ok, I can see I need to look into this more. In the meantime I'll implement your suggestion... thanks!